# Best design practice for relying on IC input diode current clamping?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, zener, diode-clamp

I have a question about what the "best design practice is" for using ICs with current clamping diodes. Take for example the following IC: CD74AC251M (datasheet : https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/texas-instruments/CD74AC251M/296-32961-5-ND/1691823)

On page 3 of the datasheet it lists a current specification of +/- 20ma for the DC inputs, rather than a voltage specification. My understanding is that this means you can exceed the supply voltage (3.3V in my case) as long as you don’t exceed the input current. Texas Instruments has an “Understanding and Interpreting Standard-Logic Data Sheets” document that was helpful with this as well (https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/405/szza036b-89603.pdf). Figure 10 indicates a clamping diode is placed on the inputs in this logic family series, as does the IC datasheet.

So, with this in mind, I want to hook up the inputs of this CD74AC251M decoder to a signal that can be from GND to 12V through a 10kOhm series resistor. If my understanding is correct, that will mean that I’m only roughly sinking 0.82mA through the input diode when the input is 12V. (12V-3.3V-0.5V = 8.2V. 8.2V/10kOhm = 0.82mA). Which is well within the input current specifications.

My question is if this is considered a "good/best" design practice. Or is it considered better practice to place an additional diode, like a 3.3V Zener, after the 10kOhm resistor as well? If so, why is that a better design?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's better to place an external clamp diode so the diode heats up instead of the IC, but you have to make sure the external diode turns on first and this can be a crapshoot unless you go for a Schottky since internal ESD clamp diodes often turn on at voltage less than 0.7V. This is different than placing a zener which will clamp independently of the rail voltage and do so even in the absence of a power supply, but also dissipate more heat (3.3V in reverse breakdown instead of 0.3V in forward conduction).

Using an external diode lets you use a smaller resistance to alleviate the RC time constant since you can dissipate more heat.

Comment: Also, these aluminum tracks on IC dice are minimal and will suffer from metal migration (from a long discussion with an IC designer at Burr Brown, Jim Todsen, years ago.) They will be spec'd large enough to handle the indicated absolute maximum. But not large enough that I'd want to consider sustained currents anywhere near that level. Worse, I recall one conversation where Jim was calling up the IC track information and realized that the path from the input pin to its destination was routed, sadly, via an all-too-narrow transfer track they hadn't caught before I called. That happens, too.

Answer (score 1):

The on_silicon clamp structures have to dump that current somewhere, and that often includes some current injected into the substrate.

The IC behaviors (such as bandgap voltage references) may be upset by currents seeking return paths.

If you use multiple opamps on one package, and expect one OpAmp to remain precision, whilst another has inputs used ESD structures to clamp over_voltages, then beware of possible errors.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it's usually bad practice to put substantial current through the input diodes in normal operation. They are designed to handle moderate ESD discharge, not for normal operation and normal operation is not guaranteed with substantial current flowing. The datasheet current limits apply in the *Absolute Maximum* section of the datasheet, the input limits during normal operation are usually something like 300mV outside the rails,  which means very little current flows, even at elevated Tj.

The current that flows can increase the power consumption, cause substantial leakage on nearby inputs, affecting analog functions, and may possibly have long term reliability issues through mechanisms such as electromigration.

I say "usually", because there's always some exception such as a consumer product where cost is overwhelmingly important and product lifetime is short.